# MPAndroidChart is there a way to set different colors for different bars?

Tags: android, view, graph, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart in my app and i was wondering if there is a way to set a diferent color for the first bar in a dynamically moving bar chart, like this:
[image]

The bars are added dynamically while the whole stack is being moved to the left as the data keeps coming, is there a way to set the color of the first bar to be a different color?
thank you in advance.

**EDIT and Solution:**
here is my code for adding a new entry to the chart, it occurs dynamically every 500 millis or so.

```
 private void addBarEntry(float value) {


    BarData data = mDownloadChart.getData();

    if(data != null) {

        BarDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        // set.addEntry(...); // can be called as well

        if (set == null) {
            set = createBarSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }

        // add a new x-value first
        data.addXValue(set.getEntryCount() + "");

        // choose a random dataSet
        //int randomDataSetIndex = (int) (Math.random() * data.getDataSetCount());

        data.addEntry(new BarEntry(value, set.getEntryCount()), 0);

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mDownloadChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        SLog.d(TAG, "download value: "+value);

        mDownloadChart.setVisibleXRange(10);
        mDownloadChart.moveViewToX(mDownloadChart.getHighestVisibleXIndex()-5);

        // redraw the chart
        mDownloadChart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Philipp Jahoda I got it to work, just add this piece of code in you addEntry method:

```
int[] colors = new int[set.getEntryCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i<colors.length; i++){
                colors[i]=Color.parseColor("your-hex-color-for-all-entries");
            }
            colors[colors.length-1] = Color.parseColor("your-hex-color-for-last-entry");

            set.setColors(colors);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is, it's in the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors).

Basically you can set a separate color for each bar in the chart. It's a little inconvenient at the moment because in your case you have to set each color to "red" and the last color to "green".

I'm working on improving that.

Comment: Thank you so much!,  i have edited my question to show the solution.

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda for (int i = 0; i < barData.getDataSetCount(); i++) {
            BarDataSet barDataSet = barData.getDataSetByIndex(i);
            //dataset is array of BarEntry
            for (int j = 0; j < barDataSet.getEntryCount(); j++) {
                BarEntry barEntry = barDataSet.getEntryForXIndex(j);
                
                if(postData.getData().get(j).getPossiblity().equals("High")){

                    barDataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor("#29C391"));
                }else{
                    barDataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @Phillipp Jahoda Could you explain more about to set separate color for individual bar in MPAndroidChart ?