# MPAndroidChart - Animating a single entry

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Using MPAndroidChart I am trying to animate a single entry like this:
[image]

is there a way to do that or at least access the single entry view so that i can animate it myself? @PhilJay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this issue, it may not be pretty but it gets the desired effect.

I have place 2 identical BarCharts on top of each other in a FrameLayout.
I add entries and move the view the same on both, on the back chart i set the last entry color to transparent like this:

```
 int[] colors = new int[set.getEntryCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i<colors.length; i++){
        colors[i]=Color.parseColor("#A4D5E9");
    }
    colors[colors.length - 1] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    set.setColors(colors);
```

On the front chart i set the last bar to be my desired color like this:

```
  int[] colors = new int[set.getEntryCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i<colors.length; i++){
            //colors[i]=Color.parseColor("#A4D5E9");
            colors[i]=Color.TRANSPARENT;
        }
        colors[colors.length - 1] = color;
        set.setColors(colors);
```

This achieves the desired result for me, for more on setting colors for specific entries, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879943/mpandroidchart-is-there-a-way-to-set-different-colors-for-different-bars) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, animating a single entry is not possible.

You will have to modify the source code of the library to achieve that feature yourself. The easiest way to do that is by creating a [fork on GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).